# How to open file from Unity with non-default application

Tags: unity, default-programs

Say I search for a recently used screenshot via Unity dash. When I click on it, it opens with the default application, in my case the image viewer. What if I want to open it with say GIMP? There is no way to do a right-click, right? And I don't want to change the default application for one case - usually I want to open pictures with the image viewer.

Do I have to go the long way and open it with the image viewer first and go to "Open with" after that? Is there no shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way, but you have to have the application with which you want the image to open, locked to the unity launcher. Provided you have done this, then drag and drop the image to it:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!